# How to get rigid body to collide with inflated soft body?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I have a mesh that inflates, that is meant to land from a short height onto a floor, which is a plane.

This sets the scene as a kind of inflated balloon/pillow on the ground.

Then I want a rigid body (actually a parented group of rigid bodies? they are all parented to one mesh) to land on the pillow, deforming it, and sort of bouncing up and off of it.

I have scoured this website and others and cannot get specific answers to my problem. Here is my current setup which allows the pillow to land on the ground, but the rigid bodies to land on the "pre-inflated" shape of the pillow mesh.

Floor-
Collision
Rigid body passive, Shape - mesh

Pillow
Cloth - Inflate
Rigid body passive, shape - mesh, deform enabled
collision

Parent of several objects
rigid body - active, shape - mesh

This is for a product animation, so i could maybe recreate a version of this if required but i dont really want to share this particular .blend.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a bug: https://developer.blender.org/T60079. You would have to switch back to 2.79 if you want this feature to work properly.

Comment: If i go back to 2.79, will i have to re do a bunch of stuff? im pretty far down the road on this project

Comment: You need to check it by yourself. Otherwise you can check when the fix is planned and wait for it. this is the task you should monitor: https://developer.blender.org/D6834